# Use Sql Server FileStream or traditional File Server?

Tags: azure, filestream

I am designing a system that's going to have about 10 millions+ users, each has a photo, which is about 1~2 MB.
We are going to deploy both database and web app using Microsoft Azure
I am wondering the way I should store the photos, there are currently two options,

## 1, Store all photos use Sql Server FileStream

## 2, Use File Server

I haven't experienced such large scale BLOB data using FileStream.

Can anybody give my any suggestion? The Cons and Pros?
And anyone with Microsoft Azure experiences concerning the large photos store is really appreciated!

Thx
Ryan.

Answer (score 7):

I vote for neither.  Use Windows Azure Blob storage.  Simple REST API, $0.15/GB/month.  You can even serve the images directly from there, if you make them public (like <img src="http://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/container/image.jpg" />), meaning you don't have to funnel them through your web app.

Answer (score 5):

Database is almost always a horrible choice for any large-scale binary storage needs. Database is best for relational-only systems, and instead, provide references in your database to the actual storage location. There's a few factors you should consider:

- Cost - SQL Azure costs quite a lot per GB of storage, and has small storage limitations (50GB per database), both of which make it a poor choice for binary data. Windows Azure Blob storage is vastly cheaper for serving up binary objects (though has a bit more complicated pricing system, still vastly cheaper per GB).
- Throughput - SQL Azure has pretty good throughput, as it can scale well, however, Windows Azure Blog storage has even greater throughput as it can scale to any number of nodes.
- Content Delivery Network - A feature not available to SQL Azure (though a complex, custom wrapper could be created), but can easily be setup within minutes to piggy-back off your Windows Azure Blob storage to provide limitless bandwidth to your end-users, so you never have to worry about your binary objects being a bottleneck in your system. CDN costs are similar to that of Blob storage, but you can find all that stuff here: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/pricing/#windows

In other words, no reason not to go with Blob storage. It is simple to use, cost effective, and will scale to any needs.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak on anything Azure related but for my money the biggest advantage of using FILESTREAM is that that data can get backed up inside the normal SQL Server backup process. The size of the data that you are talking about also suggests that FILESTREAM may be a good choice as well.

I've worked on a SCM system with a RDBMS back end and one of our big decisions was whether to store the file deltas on the file system or inside the DB itself. Because it was cross-RDBMS we had to cook up a generic non-FILESTREAM way of doing it but the ability to do a single shot backup sold us.

Answer (score 1):

FILESTREAM is a horrible option for storing images.  I'm surprised MS ever promoted it.

We're currently using it for our images on our website.  Mainly the user generated images and any CMS related stuff that admins create.  The decision to use FILESTREAM was made before I started.  The biggest issue is related to serving the images up.  You better have a CDN sitting in front.  If not, plan on your system coming to a screeching halt.  Of course, most sites have a CDN, but you don't want to be at the mercy of that service going down meaning your system will get overloaded.  The amount of stress put on your sql server is the main problem here.

In terms of ease of backup.  Your tradeoff there is that your db is MUCH MUCH LARGER and, therefore, the backup takes longer.  Potentially, much longer and the system runs slower during the backup.  Not to mention, moving backups around takes longer (i.e., restoring prod data in a dev environment or on local machines for dev purposes).  Don't use this as a deciding factor.

Most cloud services have automatic redundancy of any files that you store on their system (i.e., aws's S3 and azure's blob).  If you're on premise, just make sure you use a shared location for the images and make sure that location is backed up.  I think the best option is to set it up so each image (other UGC file types too) has an entry in your db with a path to that file.  Going one step further, separate the root path into a config setting and only store the remaining path with the entry.  For example, root path in config might be a base url, a shared drive or virtual dir, or a blank entry.  Then your entry might have "/files/images/image.jpg".  This way, if you move your filestore, you can just update the root config.  I would also suggest creating a FileStoreProvider interface (Singleton) that can be used for managing (saving, deleting, updating) these files.  This way, if you switch between AWS, Azure, or on premise, you can just create a new Provider.

Answer (score 0):

I have a client server DB, i manage many files (doc, txt, pdf, ...) and all of them go in a filestream BLOB. Customers has 50+ MB dbs. If in azure you can do the same go for it. Having all in the db is a wonderful thing. It is considered good policy also for Postgres and MySQL